# PHPUnit cahces functions from yesterday work

Tags: phpunit

I start using phpunit before literaly 20 hours. I wrote some test yestarday and now it seems they are cached. For example, this is my 3 test :

```
public function test(){
        $this->url("index.php");

        $username = $this->byName('username');
        $password = $this->byName('password');

        $this->assertEquals("", $username->value());
        $this->assertEquals("", $password->value());
    }

    public function testLoginFormSubmitsToAdmin()
    {
        $this->url("index.php");

        $form = $this->byCssSelector('form');

        $action = $form->attribute('action');
        $this->assertContains('admin.php', $action);

        $this->byName('username')->value('jeffry');
        $this->byName('password')->value('123456');
        $form->submit();

        $welcome = $this->byCssSelector('h1')->text();

        $this->assertRegExp('/(\w+){5}/i', $welcome);
    }

    public function testSubmit()
    {
        $this->url('index.php');
        $this->assertFalse($this->byId('submit')->enabled());

        $this->byName('username')->value('Az');
        $this->byName('password')->value('1234567');

        $this->assertTrue($this->byId('submit')->enabled());
    }
```

Now I am trying to make new function like `public function todayTest(){ ... }` but it didn't get executed. When I comment the other tests, run `phpunit TestLogin.php` and what I get is:

```
PHPUnit 6.5.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Time: 93 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

No tests executed!
```

It is like my function doesn't exist. If I change the name of my newly created function with the name of one of the yesterday function like - `public function test()` ( changing the name from `todayTest()` to `test()`) it works fine. Red posts around google and found something about caches but didn't understand how to clear them. Can I get some advices? Thank you!

P.S. I'm also using `Selenium 3.11.0`

Comment: PHPUnit does not use any caches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I am trying to make new function like public function todayTest(){ ... } but it didn't get executed.

It doesn't work because it is not named according to the rules followed by PHPUnit.

The [documentation of PHPUnit](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) explains how to name your files, classes and methods:

> 3. The tests are public methods that are named `test*`.
>
>    Alternatively, you can use the `@test` annotation in a method’s docblock to mark it as a test method.

Since you probably don't use the [`@test` annotation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/annotations.html#test), the method `todayTest()` is not a test but a helper method. Rename it as `testToday()` and PHPUnit will run it.

Comment: Thank you! I saw this only for the classes. Now it works :) Will mark it in green as soon as I can.